# String does not show using a bootstrap list if placed after iframe

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

How come `parsedList.title` does not show beside the embedded `iframe`?

https://jsfiddle.net/bobbyrne01/9ztgxhd7/

html

```
<div id="content">

</div>
```

javascript

```
var parsedList = [];
parsedList.push({'title': 'test', 'embed': '<iframe class="embedly-embed" src="https://cdn.embedly.com/widgets/media.html?src=https%3A%2F%2Fi.imgur.com%2F…key=2aa3c4d5f3de4f5b9120b660ad850dc9&amp;type=video%2Fmp4&amp;schema=imgur" width="200" height="160" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen&gt;&lt;/iframe>'});
parsedList.push({'title': 'test2', 'embed': '<iframe class="embedly-embed" src="https://cdn.embedly.com/widgets/media.html?src=https%3A%2F%2Fi.imgur.com%2F…key=2aa3c4d5f3de4f5b9120b660ad850dc9&amp;type=video%2Fmp4&amp;schema=imgur" width="600" height="400" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen&gt;&lt;/iframe>'});
parsedList.push({'title': 'test3', 'embed': '<iframe class="embedly-embed" src="https://cdn.embedly.com/widgets/media.html?src=https%3A%2F%2Fi.imgur.com%2F…key=2aa3c4d5f3de4f5b9120b660ad850dc9&amp;type=video%2Fmp4&amp;schema=imgur" width="300" height="160" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen&gt;&lt;/iframe>'});
parsedList.push({'title': 'test4', 'embed': '<iframe class="embedly-embed" src="https://cdn.embedly.com/widgets/media.html?src=https%3A%2F%2Fi.imgur.com%2F…key=2aa3c4d5f3de4f5b9120b660ad850dc9&amp;type=video%2Fmp4&amp;schema=imgur" width="600" height="200" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen&gt;&lt;/iframe>'});

document.getElementById('content').innerHTML = '<div class="list-group">';
for (var i = 0 ; i < parsedList.length; i++){

  if (parsedList[i].embed != null){
    parsedList[i].embed = parsedList[i].embed.replace(/width=".*?"/, 'width="200"');
    parsedList[i].embed = parsedList[i].embed.replace(/height=".*?"/, 'height="160"');
    document.getElementById('content').innerHTML += '<a href="#" class="list-group-item">' + parsedList[i].embed + parsedList[i].title + '</a>';
  }
}
document.getElementById('content').innerHTML += '</div>';
```

Comment: why the down vote?

Comment: Down vote was harsh, i have up voted to compensate for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The embed property does not have `iframe` closing tag. Here is your working code.

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/jsalaat/9ztgxhd7/2/)

```
allowfullscreen&gt;&lt;/iframe>
```

are replaced by these

```
allowfullscreen ></iframe>
```

in your `parsedList`

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Don't escape the `<` and `>` in the embed code:
`'embed': '<iframe class="embedly-embed" src="[...]" width="200" height="160" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen> </iframe>'`

https://jsfiddle.net/9ztgxhd7/3/